# Adding a new project type to Intellij new project wizard

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I am new to Intellij Plugin development. I want to add a new project type and wizard to the project type list. In the picture below some Project type under same category as Java, Java FX and Intellij Platform Plugin. I didn't find any good example on Intellij documentation. Wonder if somebody have done this before.

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to move "User-defined" just under "IntelliJ platform plugin"?